# How i can do Elastic search by all fields (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have application with Spring Boot and elastic serch.
For searching i use ElasticsearchRepository from `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository`

How i can do search by all fields with pagination?

Now my code look like that:

```
public interface ElasticRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<ModelDao, Long> {
  @Query("{\"query\": {\"match\": {\"_all\": \"?\"}}}")
    Page<ModelDao> findByAllUsingCustomQuery(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I use this interface as:

```
@Autowired
private ElasticRepo elasticRepo;

 public Page<TransportationRequestDao> getOrdersPageable(Pageable pageable, String q) {
     return elasticRepo.findByAllUsingCustomQuery(q, pageable);
 }
```

And i call this method(`getOrdersPageable`) from HTTP query

But i get answer without result.

Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

I think solve your problem by using bellow code

```
@Service
class ElasticService{
    
@Autowired
private ElasticRepo elasticRepo;
    
public List<> customQuery() {
String name = "every thing";
return elasticRepo.findByAllUsingCustomQuery(name,Pageable.of(1,20));
}
}
```

you should using `Pageable.of(1,20)` method. that first parameter is index of page and second parameter is length of items in per page.

Comment: But this is obvious! I am using similar code to use the interface `ElasticRepo`

Comment: I add this to my answer